# React FullCalendar V4 are not update the calendar view with new Events

Tags: reactjs

i'm using `FullCalendar` in my `React app`, and now i'am trying to switch to new `v4 FullCalendar` because i want to stop using the `v3 FullCalendar` with `jQuery`, at the beginning i switch to `fullcalendar-reactwrapper` library but this one has a problem in `droppable` functionality from the external events, that make me directly go and give `( v4 )` a try . it is very stable version but i did succeed to make it work with a dynamic events changing .

i made a small demo on `codesandbox` here : https://codesandbox.io/s/w2kk08j6l7

and i made one fixed event `Event 01` already exist in the events list, and after i add a new event `Event 02` the Calendar did not update as i expected .

Any suggestion are very welcome, and thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Wrong dependencies for React plus you need to put in some plugins for the calendar component. I altered your code and this works.

https://codesandbox.io/s/pedantic-mclean-cxnih

```js
import React, { Component } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import ChannelCalendar from "@fullcalendar/react";
import dayGridPlugin from "@fullcalendar/daygrid";
import timeGridPlugin from "@fullcalendar/timegrid";
import interactionPlugin from "@fullcalendar/interaction"; // needed for dayClick

import "./styles.css";

class App extends Component {
  state = {
    events: [
      {
        id: 1,
        start: "2019-08-10",
        end: "2019-08-12",
        title: "Event 01"
      }
    ]
  };
  addEvents = () => {
    const newEvent = {
      id: 2,
      start: "2019-08-18",
      end: "2019-08-21",
      title: "Event 02"
    };
    this.setState({ events: this.state.events.concat(newEvent) });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <ChannelCalendar
          plugins={[dayGridPlugin, timeGridPlugin, interactionPlugin]}
          editable={true}
          events={this.state.events}
        />
        <button onClick={this.addEvents}>Add More Events</button>

        <div>
          {this.state.events.map(event => (
            <div key={event.id}>
              {event.id} - {event.title}
            </div>
          ))}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```